# GlusterFS not Sync geo

Tags: glusterfs

I activated GlusterFS synchronization with master/slave geo location.

At first everything working, however elw does not synchronize new files, only if I stop and delete-sync-time.

The number of changes appears in the logs, but the status is only with Changelog Crawl.

In debug mode, no error message is displayed and nothing I noticed is strange.

I am finding little documentation on this problem.  I appreciate any help.

Log

```
[2021-05-04 00:09:51.21216] I [master(worker /opt/gluster-replication):1404:process] _GMaster: Batch Completed   mode=live_changelog     duration=0.8673 changelog_start=1620086988      changelog_end=1620086988        num_changelogs=1        stime=(1620086987, 0)   entry_stime=None
```

Nodes

```
MASTER NODE     MASTER VOL        MASTER BRICK                               SLAVE USER    SLAVE                                SLAVE NODE        STATUS    CRAWL STATUS       LAST_SYNCED                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10.0.0.1    infrastructure    /opt/gluster-replication    root          ssh://glusterfs02::gluster-replication    10.1.0.1    Active    Changelog Crawl    2021-05-04 00:09:47
```

Thanks.